# What role do I need to assign to give someone the ability to add alpha and beta testers in actions google console

Tags: actions-on-google, google-iam

I need someone to manage the alpha and beta testers for our Google Actions development.

They are not involved in any other aspect of development and so I want to keep their rights as restricted as possible.

I only want them to be able to add and remove alpha and beta testers and to be able to access the link that can be sent to those testers to invite them.

What Roles do I need to assign within IAM to enable this, if I can not do this exactly what is the nearest I can get, without giving away too much access?

Comment: Use Google Groups. Assign users to a group. Add the group to IAM with desired IAM roles. In Google Groups, you can control who can modify a group. Note: I am assuming you do not have Google G Suite which is another option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure this response answers my question.  I know how to use IAM to define groups and allocate people to them.  What I am looking for is the exact combination of permissions I should allocate to someone if the only thing they are allowed to do is add/remove people from alpha and beta whitelists

Comment: Sorry, then I do not understand your question. Edit your question to be clearer on what you are trying to do.